# What does "i" in "for i in range ()" mean?

Tags: python, for-loop

I understand what "for" and "range" do in for-loops, but can't get what exactly "i" does in them. Can you explain?

Comment: It is a variable. What you call your variables is up to you.

Comment: Try `for i in range(10): print(i)`

Comment: the variable that represent the current element of the iteration. so it takes all the values given by the range

Comment: You can think of `range` as a returning a list (not true, but accurate enough for now). What the `for _ in range(_):` construct does then, is take each element in the "list" returned by `range`, and assigns `i` to the elements value. This way you have access to every value in the list `range` returns.

Comment: If you are interested in the history of computer science, check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147312/who-invented-i-j-k-as-integer-counter-variable-names

Otherwise, as above answers go, its just a name for a loop variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a variable that is an iterable used in the for-loop (in this case, range(x))

`i` can be changed out with any other character or word, i recommend you used `i` as your standard practice or something which relates to what you are looping.

`range(x)` can also be changed out for any iterable. For example:

```
names = ['janet', ' bob', 'charlie']
for name in names:
    print(name)

# Output: janet bob charlie
```

More examples of for-loops:

```
grid = [[0, 1, 2], 
        [3, 4, 5], 
        [6, 7, 8]]

for row in grid:
    print(row)

# Outputs:
# [0, 1, 2]
# [3, 4, 5]
# [6, 7, 8]

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        print(grid[col][row])

# Outputs: 0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8
# Prints a single digit at a time going from the first of each array to the last
# Instead of printing out an array at a time
```